# How to change the value of a variable inside mysql.query() method

Tags: mysql, node.js

**Here is my code.**

I am new to nodejs and, I am querying to the mysql database using mysql package. I have two variables i.e. hasCouponCode and isVerifiedUser and by default they are set to false. So I want to set the value of hasCouponCode to true if the couponCode exists in db and value of isVerifiedUser to true if user exists in mysql db. But I am not able to set their values to true. Then how can I change/set its value?

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
   const { name, email, couponCode } = req.body;

   let hasCouponCode = false, isVerifiedUser = false;

   pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
      if (err) {
         throw err;
      }

      connection.query(`SELECT * FROM coupons WHERE couponCode='${couponCode}'`, (couponError, couponRows) => {
         if (couponError) {
            throw couponError;
         }

         if (!couponRows.length > 0) {
            console.log('Coupon not found...❌');
         }

         console.log('Coupon found...✔️');
         hasCouponCode = true;
      });

      connection.query(`SELECT name FROM users WHERE name='${name}'`, (userError, userRows) => {
         if (userError) {
            throw userError;
         }

         if (!userRows.length > 0) {
            console.log('User not found...❌');
         }

         console.log('User found...✔️');
         isVerifiedUser = true;
      });

      connection.release();
   });

   console.log(hasCouponCode, isVerifiedUser);

   res.redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: what sort of value are we expecting from couponCode in the table? is it a number or boolean?

Comment: Its a number 10 digit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
connection.query(`SELECT * FROM coupons WHERE couponCode =10`, (couponError, couponRows) => {
         if (couponError) {
            throw couponError;
         }

         if (couponRows.length) {   
           console.log('Coupon found...✔️');
           hasCouponCode = true;
         }else{
           console.log('Coupon not found...❌');
         }

      });

      connection.query(`SELECT name FROM users WHERE name='${name}'`, (userError, userRows) => {
         if (userError) {
            throw userError;
         }

         if (userRows.length) {
            console.log('User found...✔️');
            isVerifiedUser = true;
         }else{
            console.log('User not found...❌');
         }

      });

      connection.release();
```